How to determine which event is the conditional event?
I know generally conditional probability questions are presented in the form: "What is the probability of Event A given Event B," and from there it can be written as:
$P(A|B)$
However, how is that determined when the question doesn't explicitly state the given condition?
For example, if we have a question such as, "What is the probability that a randomly selected baseball player is a pitcher who voted "Yes" on the team questionnaire?"
Would it be
$P($Pitcher | Voted Yes$)$
or
$P($Voted Yes| Pitcher$)$
Thank you!

It's neither.  For conditional probability you assume that one event happened, and then ask for the probability that an additional event also happened.  Here, you aren't assuming either event.  Here you are  asked for $P(\text {Pitcher}\cap \text {Voted Yes})$
Conditional statements would be, for instance, "Given that the player you selected voted Yes, what is the probability that you selected a Pitcher?"  or "Given that the player you selected was a Pitcher, what is the probability that he voted Yes?".

Thank you so much for the clarification! That helps a lot.

Shouldn't it rather be $P(\text {Pitcher}\cap \text {Voted Yes} \mid \text{Baseball Player})$?

@md2pere that's part of the given universe.  If you pick random cards from a deck,  you don't then specify that you have chosen from a deck.

@md2perpe phrased differently, conditioning on an event with probability  $1$ doesn't have an impact.

@lulu. But we could consider our universe be all people.
